# Use integer for relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, mariadb, symfony4

I'm implementing a REST API, and I would like to implement a quick and easy way to create and persist entities.

Therefore, I created an entity like so, where `$plain` is a basic associative array:

```php
    public function __construct($plain = null)
    {
        if ($plain != null) {
            foreach ($plain as $k => $v) {
                if (property_exists($this, $k))
                    $this->{$k} = $v;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Property $k does not exist in " . self::class);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;
```

My frontend input will look something like this, and then decoded into the `$plain` array from above:

```
{
    "name": "FooBar",
    "parent": 1
}
```

When flushing, I'm greeted by a totally understandable Doctrine error, telling me that `$parent` is an integer and is not an entity as expected.

I'd like to mention that here, the "parent" will never be fetched by the backend, as I'm creating a new entity, all I want to do is write `1` in the `parent_id` column of my database.

To summarize, my goal is to make doctrine write the id in the database column, without checking for context.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: When you specify "without checking for context", that makes me think this is going to be quite awkward and tricky. The whole point of the ORM is to decouple you from database concerns like writing foreign IDs to express relationships.

Comment: I'm not certain it won't be checked, but have a look at `getReference` - https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/21bc805dc9662ff05f3038b30a29e05591838a29/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L465 however, since the entitiy itself should not have an $em inside, this would be done by some smart repository function, i would say ...